# What is the C# equivalent of the Delphi MatchesMask function?

Tags: c#, delphi, c#-4.0

What is the equivalent of the Delphi [`MatchesMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Masks.MatchesMask) function in C# .NET ? How can I use it, and which namespace reference do I need to include ?

The [`MatchesMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Masks.MatchesMask) function as described in help:

> Indicates whether a file name conforms to the format specified by a
>   filter string.
>
> Call MatchesMask to check the Filename parameter using the Mask
>   parameter to describe valid values. A valid mask consists of literal
>   characters, sets, and wildcards.
>
> Each literal character must match a single character in the string.
>   The comparison to literal characters is case-insensitive.
>
> Each set begins with an opening bracket ([) and ends with a closing
>   bracket (]). Between the brackets are the elements of the set. Each
>   element is a literal character or a range. Ranges are specified by an
>   initial value, a dash (-), and a final value. Do not use spaces or
>   commas to separate the elements of the set. A set must match a single
>   character in the string. The character matches the set if it is the
>   same as one of the literal characters in the set, or if it is in one
>   of the ranges in the set. A character is in a range if it matches the
>   initial value, the final value, or falls between the two values. All
>   comparisons are case-insensitive. If the first character after the
>   opening bracket of a set is an exclamation point (!), then the set
>   matches any character that is not in the set.
>
> Wildcards are asterisks (*) or question marks (?). An asterisk matches
>   any number of characters. A question mark matches a single arbitrary
>   character.
>
> MatchesMask returns true if the string matches the mask. MatchesMask
>   returns false if the string does not match the mask. MatchesMask
>   raises an exception if the mask is syntactically invalid.
>
> Note: The Filename parameter does not need to be a file name. MatchesMask can be used to check strings against any syntactically
>   correct mask.

Comment: Could you provide a briefing about this function?

Answer (score 5):

Modern programming languages provide Regular Expression engines that allows to do matching of patterns.

C# provides Regex class that can be used in following manner:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // First we see the input string.
        string input = "/content/alternate-1.aspx";

        // Here we call Regex.Match.
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"content/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.aspx$",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
            string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(key);
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer to following links for quick reference

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match (above example is from this site)
- http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet (quick cheat sheet - quite handy)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(v=vs.80).aspx (MS programming reference)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.Text.RegularExpressions` to compare data with regular expression to implement a mask