# What is the equivalent of ? in MatchesMask of delphi in regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, delphi

Delphi's [MatchesMask](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Masks.MatchesMask) documentation says this about `?` (emphasis mine):

> Wildcards are asterisks (*) or question marks (?). An asterisk matches any number of characters. **A question mark matches a single arbitrary character.**

My question: is `?` in `MatchesMask` equivalent to `.` in regex? Or is it equivalent to `.?` in regex? As far as I can tell, there is a difference between the two. `.` matches exactly *one* non-newline character, whereas `.?` matches *zero or one* non-newline character.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828908/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-the-delphi-matchesmask-function) but it didn't help much, apart from telling me to use regex for `MatchesMask`.

---

In case it helps, what I actually want to do is convert some delphi code into C#, where I came across this code, where `myMask` is a string ending with a few `?`:

```pascal
if MatchesMask(myString, myMask) then begin  // myMask has value '100-10???'
  Result := True;
  exit;
end;
```

Comment: @MYGz Surely that *is* the case with regex. But how does delphi's `?` work? Does it require to be prefixed with something? Please also note that in the source code I am converting, the mask has several `?` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` in MatchesMask matches any single arbitrary character, just like the `?` in a DOS wildcard. The specific mask you've indicated ('100-10???') requires the string `100-10` followed by three arbitrary characters.

The equivalent regular expression would be

```
100-10.{3}
```

which matches

```
100-10abc
100-10ABC
100-10X12
100-10399
```

but does not match

```
100-20abc
100-22xyz
100-10
100-101
100-1023
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I also use `100-10...` to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I suppose so, but why would you want to? It's not as clear when you read it. And couldn't you test it yourself to see if it worked?

Comment: Just wondering if that would work or not. I think that was just a stupid comment. And no, I can't test it, coz I don't have _anything_ where I can step through the delphi code. :-(

Comment: You don't have to step through the Delphi code to find out if a regular expression works in C#. It's also rather rude to tell someone who is trying to help you that they're stupid.

Comment: Ooops, yeah right, looks like I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: BTW, you got it wrong man. I was saying my comment asking if `100-10...` would work was stupid, not yours. Sorry, for not making it clear in the first place. I am always grateful to all people that help me ;-)